# Common folder in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, shared

I have two users on my Ubuntu machine.  I want to share some media files between these users, so I created a directory in /home/ called 'media'.  I made the group 'media' and I added my user 'rks171' to the group 'media'.  So:

```
sudo groupadd media
sudo mkdir -p /home/media
sudo chown -R root.media /home/media 
sudo chmod g+s /home/media
```

As was described in [this post.](https://superuser.com/questions/88874/where-on-a-linux-file-system-should-someone-put-media-intended-to-be-accessible)

Then, I added my user to the group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G media rks171
```

Then I also added write permission to this folder for my group:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w media
```

So now, doing 'ls -lh' gives:

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 root   media  4.0K Oct  6 09:46 media
```

I tried to copy pictures to this new directory from my user directory:

```
mv /home/rks171/Pictures/* /home/media/
```

And I get 'permission denied'.  I can't understand what's wrong.

If I simply type, 'id', it doesn't show that my user, rks171, is part of the 'media' group.  But if I type, 'id rks171', then it does show that my user, rks171, is part of the 'media' group.  Anybody have any ideas why I can't get an files into this common folder?

Comment: *"Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the FAQ."* You might have better luck asking this at [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry about that.  All these 'stack' sites look so similar.  I posted it on 'superuser', which is where I first found the post relating to creating a shared folder.  If it is answered, I'll post the answer back here for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I'm re-posting the answer to this question here.  It was simply a matter of logging out and back in to create a new session.  This allowed my addition to the group to take effect.